# No administrators were specified

Tags: facebook-like, admin

I am very new to facebook platform. I am facing an issue with like button in some of our pages. This is happening on claires.com site

When I test the below  URLs through developers.facebook.com/tools/debug page one is working fine and the other one is failing

This URL works fine http://www.claires.com/store/style-files/Leopard-And-Gold/5600037
This one giving me an error http://www.claires.com/store/goods/Teens/cat310104/Drops/p45198/Feather-Fabulosity-Earrings/

When I inspect the source for the both of the pages I am seeing same parameters provided for both pages.

This is the error I am getting for the second url "The page failed to provide a valid list of administrators. It needs to specify the administrators using either a "fb:app_id" meta tag, or using a "fb:admins" meta tag to specify a comma-delimited list of Facebook users."

But I wonder why this error is happening on one page and not happening in the other page, both provides same kind of meta values

Please let me know what went wrong here...

Thanks
-Sujith

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by adding these namespaces to your HTML tag on your website:

```
<html ...  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Courtesy of: http://blitzkriegconsultant.blogspot.com/